# RecordType.DeveloperName works in Sandbox1 but not Sandbox2

Tags: visual-workflow, sandbox, record-type, change-set, spring-20

I created a flow that starts off with a "Get Record" element for the current Opportunity.

I then check the record Type this way:

{!Get_CurrentOpp.RecordType.DeveloperName} I check the value and execute several logical steps. This works completely fine in Sandbox 1 for our devs.

But after deploying the change set to a training sandbox (Sandbox 2), I am getting an error that says "a value has not been set" when I go and check the flow, it is no longer accepting the {!Get_CurrentOpp.RecordType.DeveloperName} notation. However, if I run a SOQL query on Opportunity displaying current value RecordType.DeveloperName, I still get values.

Any advice on how to fix this bug without having to refactor the entire flow?

Comment: I would check if the record type active in destination org and available to current user?

Comment: It's active and available.

Comment: Is either of these on Spring 20?

Comment: The Spring 20 pre-release is active in our Sandbox 1. Our Sandbox 2 does not have the release yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Kris Goncalves for that breadcrumb about release versions. Flow apparently got a significant change, specifically on the Get Records element. The update that is coming in Spring 20 is the reason. The screenshots below demonstrate the change, but there appear to be several other changes that I'm finding as I refactor the app to match the old version.

### Sandbox 1:

[image]

### Sandbox 2:

[image]